# Serializing JSon different decimal separators for same type

Tags: c#, json

I try to serialize a complex object which has double values and 3D points as properties.

The 3D points' X,Y,Z properties are also double.

When I serialize the object via Newtonsoft.Json, I find the double properties separated by dot, but the X,Y,Z values of points are separated by comma.

Here is my classes :

```
  public class FootScan : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private double _footLength;
   public double FootLength
   {
       get { return _footLength; }
       set
       {
          if (value == _footLength)
              return;
          _footLength = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("FootLength");
       }
   }

    private Point3D _firstMet;
    public Point3D FirstMet
    {
        get { return _firstMet; }
        set
        {
            _firstMet = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstMet");
        }
    }
   ...
  }


public class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    public double Angle { get; set; }
    public CustomPoint3D()
    {

    }

    public CustomPoint3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
}
```

Serialization :

```
           var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CurrentScan);
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(pth + "\\ScanObject.json", FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
```

And the result in json file :

```
FootLength: 263.5
FirstMet:   "-29,832, 188,075, -2,137"
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Did you check your given minimal reproducible example? Does this compile if you remove the `...`? (hint: the answer is "no"). Does it produce the result you gave? (hint: answer is "no") The whole thing gives me the feeling you did not bother spending enough time creating this question and in that quickness forgot to add the actual code that is creating your problem.

Comment: But as a hint to a possible solution (can't say without the actual code): in your result it's clear that `Point3D` is not converted normally but somehow ends up as some string representation. My assumption is that that string representation is done using your local culture settings (display the decimal seperator as a ',') and then the `FootLength` is serialized by `NewtonSoft` and correctly does a culture insensitive representation of the double in json with a '.' as decimal seperator.

Comment: This is a huge project and unfortunately I can not publish all the class because it will be too large. I reduced the code, and assure you, it wasn't quick, to reproduce the minimal code which gives the same result.  So All hints that says no, aren't no actually. Thanks for your advices.